# detect home button pressed

Tags: android, button

I want to detect if user pressed home button, i don't need to change it's behaviour. how can i implement it?
i tried this solution, but i got exception

```
 Android - Error - IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added
```

source

```
 @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
    }
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME){
        mPager.stopAutoScroll();
        Log.d("Pager", "Autoscroll stopped");
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Solution in [dublicate]topic is not working on android l on my device**

**Correct solution**

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

      public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
      }  

      public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;
      }

      public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
      }

      private static boolean activityVisible;
    }
```

Register your application class in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <application
        android:name="your.app.package.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Add onPause and onResume to every Activity in the project (you may create a common ancestor for your Activities if you'd like to, but if your activity is already extended from MapActivity/ListActivity etc. you still need to write the following by hand):

```
       @Override
        protected void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
mPager.startAutoScroll();
          MyApplication.activityResumed();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
          super.onPause();
          MyApplication.activityPaused();
mPager.stopAutoScroll();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the onAttachedToWindow method, so try to reverse the order of both lines - first do what you want and then call the super method like this:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();           
}
```

Comment: no, got the same exception